# "Connection refused" Boost.Beast library for the C++ WebSocket client

Tags: python, c++, websocket, boost

I have this Python code:

```
Server.py

import asyncio
import websockets
import random

async def random_number(websocket, path):
    while True:
        number = random.randint(1, 100)
        await websocket.send(str(number))
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

start_server = websockets.serve(random_number, "localhost", 8765)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

which sends random numbers via localhost:8765. I tested that and it works with a different Python script:

```
Client.py

import asyncio
import websockets

async def websocket_client():
    uri = "ws://localhost:8765"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        while True:
            message = await websocket.recv()
            print(f"Received: {message}")

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(websocket_client())
```

Now, I want to go further and involve C++. Basically I want to be able to do in C++ exactly what Client.py is doing. Hence, I wrote:

```
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/connect.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http = beast::http;
namespace websocket = beast::websocket;
namespace net = boost::asio;
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    try {
        const std::string host = "localhost";
        const std::string port = "8765";
        const std::string target = "/";

        net::io_context ioc;
        tcp::resolver resolver{ioc};
        websocket::stream<tcp::socket> ws{ioc};

        auto const results = resolver.resolve(host, port);
        net::connect(ws.next_layer(), results.begin(), results.end());

        ws.handshake(host + ':' + port, target);

        for (;;) {
            beast::flat_buffer buffer;
            ws.read(buffer);
            std::string message = beast::buffers_to_string(buffer.data());
            std::cout << "Received: " << message << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

And I get: **Error: connect: Connection refused**
What is going on?

Comment: Dunno how much help it would be but maybe try `websocket::stream<beast::tcp_stream>` as your websocket stream type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me, so that suggests that something about your environment is different.

Maybe `localhost` doesn't actually resolve to `127.0.0.1` or a firewall interferes. You might sidestep the first by connecting directly e.g. changing

```
    auto const results = resolver.resolve(host, port);
    net::connect(ws.next_layer(), results.begin(), results.end());
```

To

```
    ws.next_layer().connect({{}, 8765});
```

Otherwise, I'd suggest looking at the network packets with wireshark/ethereal/tcpdump et al. to find any difference that might be relevant.

Live demo locally for me using the code supplied:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem turned out to be caused by the fact that I am using PyCharm to run Python code (Windows), but I am running my C++ code on WSL with Visual Studio Code, so the problem was related to the combination Windows-WSL. So, indeed localhost should not direct to 127.0.0.1, but rather to the IP address of my Windows host from within WSL2, so I had to change this in the Python code.